# Pop-up login close when clicked on recover password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With this code, when a user click inside my pop-up form this pop-up stay. But when the user click in the `?` to recover the password the pop-up for that is showed, but doesnt close the login form.

Any ideas how to close the login pop-up??

HTML Code:

```
   <div id="joinusLogin">
        <div id="backgroundOpacity"></div>
        <form id="loginForm">
            <input id="loginFormFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder=" E-mail"/><br />
                <input id="loginFormFields" type="text" name="password" placeholder=" Password"/>
                <div id="requestPassword">
                    <a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('passwordRecover'))">?</a>
                </div>
            <br />
                <input id="submitLogin" type="submit" value="LOG IN"/>
        </form>

        <div id="signupNow">
            Don't have an account yet? 
            <a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('inviteNowSignup'))">
                Sign up here.
            </a> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="passwordRecover">
        <div id="backgroundOpacity"></div>
            <form id="passwordRecoverForm">
                <input id="passwordRecoverFields" type="email" name="email" placeholder=" E-mail"/><br />
                    <input id="submitPasswordRecover" type="submit" value="SEND PASSWORD"/>
            </form>

        <div id="signupNow">
            Don't have an account yet? 
            <a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('inviteNowSignup'))">
                Sign up here.
            </a> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javscript Code

```
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById)
    return
if (which.style.display=="block")
    which.style.display="none"
else
    which.style.display="block"
}

$('body').click(function(){
  $('#inviteNowSignup, #joinusLogin, #passwordRecover').hide();
});

$('body').on('click',"#signupForm, #loginForm, #passwordRecoverForm",function (e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thats because your hideshow function does display:block to the element you want but not hiding other elements.
Call this $('#inviteNowSignup, #joinusLogin').hide(); in the first line of that function

Comment: @SSS if you want, feel free to create an answer, and i will accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in your code. You have handled the opening and closing of those elements which have been clicked and passed to your function. But you have not handled those which are already open.

Try to add this line before the function

```
   $('#inviteNowSignup, #joinusLogin').hide();
```

It will hide the other divs.
BTW nice work with single function to hide and unhide.